# Django request.body has incomplete data

Tags: android, django, python-2.7, api, android-volley

I am sending a large amount of data to the server from Android App using Volley. The request which I receive in Django, **sometimes** has incomplete data.

While doing `json.loads(data)` it throws `ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 278491 (char 278490)`.

It doesn't happen every time.

What can be the possible error in my **Django** or **Android** Code?

Sample Code:

```
request_data = request.body
data = json.loads(request_data)
```

- I am using Python 2.7

Comment: post the request data.

Comment: I have checked, the data is incomplete. It doesn't have complete json. The string which i am getting has not proper json format. It couldn't find ending of brackets for json object and json array. Can't post complete data here. Its quite long.

Comment: Its ending unexpectedly : {"address":"123456789","body":"By mistake","date":"T

Comment: How big is your data in `megabytes`?

Comment: Its less than 6MB

Answer (score 2):

Tuning [DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size) setting will help you tune according to your needs.